# CSS3 gradient for background-image opacity

Tags: html, css

I have a background image for a hero element on a website that I'm working on. I want to make the background image in the .hero div be on a gradient from transparency to complete opacity on the edges so the backgrounds of both divs blend into each other.

To illustrate, here's the code that I'm using right now in the body of my `index.html`:

```
<div class="hero">
    <div class="hero-inner">
         <h1>My awesome hero element</h1>
    </div>
</div>
```

... and this is what's in my `style.css`

```
.hero {
    background-color: black;
    width: 800px;
}

.hero-inner {
    width: 700px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: auto;
    background-image: url('http://i.imgur.com/PXzVXmR.png');
}
.hero-inner h1 {
    position: absolute;
    font-family: Arial, sans-serif;
    color: white;
    padding: 10px;
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.7);
    left: 50px;
    top: 20px;
    font-size: 48px;
}
```

[Here's the jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/X3K83/). How would I make the background image in `.hero-inner` blend in with the background color of `.hero` on the edges? I've got a similar effect on Photoshop that does the job but I'd like to know if this could be done with CSS3 gradients

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can draw radial background gradient, but code is really ugly and looks heavy.

Here is a gradient editor that may be useful: http://www.colorzilla.com/gradient-editor/

```
background: -moz-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,48,48,1) 23%, rgba(205,57,71,1) 40%, rgba(80,79,130,0) 83%, rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
background: -webkit-gradient(radial, center center, 0px, center center, 100%, color-stop(23%,rgba(255,48,48,1)), color-stop(40%,rgba(205,57,71,1)), color-stop(83%,rgba(80,79,130,0)), color-stop(100%,rgba(30,87,153,0)));
background: -webkit-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,48,48,1) 23%,rgba(205,57,71,1) 40%,rgba(80,79,130,0) 83%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
background: -o-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,48,48,1) 23%,rgba(205,57,71,1) 40%,rgba(80,79,130,0) 83%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
background: -ms-radial-gradient(center, ellipse cover, rgba(255,48,48,1) 23%,rgba(205,57,71,1) 40%,rgba(80,79,130,0) 83%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, rgba(255,48,48,1) 23%,rgba(205,57,71,1) 40%,rgba(80,79,130,0) 83%,rgba(30,87,153,0) 100%);
filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.gradient( startColorstr='#ff3030', endColorstr='#001e5799',GradientType=1 );
```

Comment: The jsFidle you provided has the same URL as the original one from the question. Is this a mistake or did you update the original jsFiddle?

Comment: @davblayn  yes sorry, mistake. but you can play with gradient editor to get what you need.

Comment: Ok, thanks for that information. It is a lot of ugly code (*cough* Internet Explorer) but I'll have a shot at it and if that doesn't work I'll look into adding gradients using Photoshop